# Issue with CSS bundling when publishing ASP.NET MVC Application

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-5, publish

I'm trying to publish my ASP.NET MVC 5 Application on a local network Server, The CSS files that i've had bundled in my Layout view aren't found (the bundle definition in bundleConfig.cs is

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));
```

), when i replace the 
`@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")`
 with

```
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

it works.

Comment: Post your bundle definition for `"~/Content/css"`

Comment: Did you find the solution?